# Most effective substring of an MD5 checksum

Tags: md5, substring

If I want a shorter MD5 checksum, should I take the regular one and use the first half or the second half? Or does it even matter?

(obviously it would cease to be an MD5, it would just be a checksum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter, but I'd think very hard about doing this: you'll greatly increase the chance of a collision (two different bits of data with the same checksum).

Comment: Thank you everyone. Each answer seems equally helpful, I am accepting this one because it is the first answer and because Dan here has only 13 reputation. That tips the scale so at least I am not torn.

Answer (score 3):

Use some sort of a [CNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) hashing function if you need a short string. Be aware that it isn't a very safe, but it will be still better than taking the half of a MD5.

Comment: Why would it be better? Even a truncated MD5 would have better distribution and security properties than a simple CRC. Only advantage of a typical CRC is performance.

Comment: Maintainability! It wouldn't be something special no other developer will understand by seeing a weird half MD5 string. If you need a shorter string than MD5 you should go with a standard implementation which was build to produce a short hashing string. Just my 2 cents ;)

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't matter. Generally speaking the entire checksum changes for each input byte. But if you can't decide, why not xor the first half with the second? :-)